# Need help finding my lost iPod 5

Tags: ipod-touch

I lost my iPod 5 a few days ago, I'm pretty sure it's sill in my house. Is there a way to turn the Wi-Fi on my iPod or thru my a Apple account?

Comment: was it on or off when you lost it ?

Comment: It was on just a few minuets before it vanished.

Comment: Do you remember what apps you had open that would make noise. Like Skype, Facebook, Twitter, email, and other notifications.

Comment: If it is on and if Find my iPod is on and the iPod is connected to the Internet, go to icloud.com, sign in if not already, go to the Find my iPhone App and locate your device in the menu or on the map. Click on the menue item/the dot on the map and you'll see a little window pop up. There you can play a sound to locate the iPod.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for iCloud to connect to an offline iPod if WiFi is off.

Maybe if Bluetooth is on, and you had a speaker or other Bluetooth device paired to it, roaming through the house with it may activate the link and give you an idea of where it can be.